# mkdir returns false when the directory already exists ( on Windows )

Tags: php

The PHP version is 5.5.12 ( under WAMP 2.5 )

I want to create a `directory` recursively , it is on my development computer Windows7 at the moment but the production system is Linux :

```
define('RP_MAIN', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'impots/');
$dir = RP_MAIN."data/synchro/webToAndroid/";
if (mkdir($dir, 0777, true)) {
   ... // creating text files with data inside the webToAndroid folder
} else {
    echo "cannot create";
}
```

At first run of the script the directory is created , but when I rerun the script then the code execution goes to the `else` block !

So how to make the `mkdir` always succeed ?

Comment: What do you want to do if the directory already exists. Just leave the existing one, or delete it and create a new dir, or something else?

Comment: I do not know how to test if the directory already exists !

Comment: use `file_exists()` before `mkdir()`

Comment: use `is_dir()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Comment: Are you *really* sure you want to create a 777 directory under the document root? I'd be slightly surprised if the Apache user on the server even had permissions to do that.

Comment: what should I put then instead of 0777 ?

Comment: Ideally the web server should never be able to create files/folders within the document root - it should never be able to write to anywhere that can be read over HTTP - so if HTTP access isn't required to anything in that folder write to a location **outside of the web tree**. The permissions mask is User / Group / Nobody (i.e. guest *nix user); if Apache is the owner of the folder and anything within and you never need to touch it with SFTP then you'll probably want 700; if you need SFTP permissions and the SFTP user is in the same group as Apache, 770 (probably).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
define('RP_MAIN', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'impots/');
$dir = RP_MAIN."data/synchro/webToAndroid/";
if(is_dir($dir)){
   echo 'directory already exists';
}
else if (mkdir($dir, 0777, true)) {
  ... // creating text files with data inside the webToAndroid folder
} else {
   echo "cannot create";
}
```

Comment: is `file_exists` more accurate ?

Comment: `file_exists` checks if a given file or directory exists. `is_dir` checks if the supplied string is actually a directory. Both will do just fine in this instance.